# Combo box link is not working after clicking

Tags: combobox

```
<form name="mycombowopt">
    <select  name="example" size=1>
        <option value="http://javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</option>
        <option value="http://cnn.com">CNN</option>
        <option value="http://geocities.com">Geocities</option>
   </select>&nbsp;
   <input type="button" value="Go!" onClick="gothere()"> <br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="windowoption" value="ON">Open in alternate window</p>
</form>

<script language="javascript">
<!--


function gothere(){
    var thebox=document.mycombowopt
    if (thebox.windowoption.checked){
        if (!window.newwindow)
        newwindow=window.open("")
        newwindow.location=
        thebox.example.options[thebox.example.selectedIndex].value
    }
    else
    location=
    thebox.example.options[thebox.example.selectedIndex].value
}
//-->
</script>
```

Whats wrong with this code? The combo box is not working after linking "Go" on my [question answers website][1].

```
  [1]: http://www.ihavesolved.com/
```

Can you provide the code for combo box with the following:-

Background = white color
Title:- Partner Sites
Links inside dropdownbox = I Have Solved (url=www.iнaveѕolved.coм), Space Amigos
(spaceamigos.com) and Surak.szh.kz (url=Surak.szh.kz)

Links must open in new windows and the links must be nofollow.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Background = white color Title:- Partner Sites.

Comment: Links must open in new windows and the links must be nofollow.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
window.open
```

instead of

```
location
```

This javascript code is working for me.

```
function gothere(){
        var thebox=document.mycombowopt
        if (thebox.windowoption.checked){
            if (!window.newwindow)
            //newwindow=window.open("")
            //newwindow.location=thebox.example.options[thebox.example.selectedIndex].value

            window.open(
              thebox.example.options[thebox.example.selectedIndex].value,
              '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
            );
        }
        else{
            //location=thebox.example.options[thebox.example.selectedIndex].value   
            window.open(
              thebox.example.options[thebox.example.selectedIndex].value,
              '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
            );
        }

    }
```